# Search/Replace in Vim

Tags: regex, vim, vi, replace

I want to delete all occurrences of square brackets that conform to this regex: `\[.*\].*{`, but I only want to delete the brackets, not what follows - i.e., I want to delete the brackets and what's inside them, only when they are followed by an opening curly brace.

How do I do that with Vim's search/replace?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `\zs` and `\ze` to set the beginning and the end of the match.

`:%s/\zs\[.*\]\ze.*{//g` should work.

You are telling Vim to replace what is between `\zs` and `\ze` by an empty string.

(Note that you need the +syntax option compiled in your Vim binary)

For more information, see `:help /\zs` or `:help pattern`

**Edit** : Actually \zs is not necessary in this case but I leave it for educational purpose. :)

Comment: I had no idea this existed!  Excellent tip!

Answer (score 6):

If you surround the last bit of your regex in parenthesis you can re-use it in your replace:

```
:%s/\[.*\]\(.*{\)/\1/g
```

The \1 references the part of the regex in parenthesis.

I like to build my search string before I use it in the search and replace to make sure it is right before I change the document:

```
/\[.*\]\(.*{\)
```

This will highlight all the occurrances of what you will replace.
Then run the %s command without a search term to get it to re-use the last search term

```
:%s//\1/g
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this mostly because it shows me what the token is for replacing groups, I'm used to using `$1` for the replace term but clearly its `\1`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
:%s#\[.*\]\ze.*{##g
```

Note that the `\ze` item marks the end of the match, so anything that follows is not replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This will run your regex on the current file:

`:%s/\[.*\]\(.*{\)/\1/g`

Comment: That's exactly my problem, I want to keep the curly brace and only delete the brackets and what's inside them.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't sure if you just needed the syntax for regex in vim. I edited my answer with another possible solution, though there are now several working answers posted.